# Get result of command-line in C program

Tags: c, command-line

Is there a way to read in the result of a command-line in a C program?

For example, if I have the following code in a C program

```
sprintf(command, "cat input_file.txt | wc -l");
system(command);
```

can I get the result of the `wc -l` and store it in a variable so I can use it in the same C program?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, look into [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), if you have it.

In general, you must spawn a sub-process and set up a pipe to read its standard output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int num_line;
   char *command="cat input_file.txt | wc -l";
   FILE *p=popen(command,"r");
   fscanf(p,"%d",&num_line);
   printf("%d\n",num_line);
   pclose(p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better use `fscanf` to avoid buffering.